# How do I stop a stored procedure or ASP page from corrupted unicode strings?

Tags: string, unicode

I have a database that has already corrupted unicode strings, now on my ASP page, they are shown as "?" marks. Is there a way either to stop them from being returned down at the stored procedure level? or is the best way to stop them from showing up on the asp page is to somehow detect the corrupted unicode strings and stop them from being shown.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dear Wajih, I'm not sure that I underestand you completly,

I underestood that you have a database with some data (like Arabic words). Youalso have an Asp.net page whichdisplay these words as `?`.

If these are right, then you can resolve your issue by add

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

To your `Asp page Header`

then in SQL Server, when you are reading this data you have to put **`N`** before the filed name.

if you haveanother problem please tellme more and update your question with a sample data from your sql Tables and a picture from your final **Asp Source Code**